# How can I optimize this short code?

Tags: recursion

I wrote two versions of this code which have similar performances.
I'd like to know if it is possible to further optimize this code:

```
g = 0.01;
alfa[n_, t_] := g*t*Sqrt[n + 1];
beta[n_, t_, pe_] :=pe*Cos[alfa[n, t]]^2 + (1 - pe)*Cos[alfa[n - 1, t]]^2;

vettore3[t_, pe_, N_] := 
Module[{pg, vec0, vec1, alfan, betan, sinalfan1, sinalfan2, cosalfan},
pg = 1 - pe;
alfan = Prepend[ParallelTable[alfa[n, t], {n, 0, N}], 0];
sinalfan1 = Drop[Sin[alfan]^2, 1];
sinalfan2 = Drop[Sin[alfan]^2, -1];
cosalfan = Cos[alfan]^2;
betan = pe*Drop[cosalfan, 1] + (1 - pe)*Drop[cosalfan, -1];
vec0 = Prepend[ConstantArray[0, N],1];
Monitor[For[i = 0, i < N, i++,
vec1 = betan*vec0 + Prepend[Drop[pe*sinalfan1*vec0, -1], 0] + 
Drop[Append[pg*sinalfan2*vec0, 0], 1];
vec0 = vec1;], Framed[i]]; Return[vec1]]

vettore4[t_, pe_, N_] := 
Module[{pg, vec, alfan, betan, sinalfan1, sinalfan2, cosalfan},
$RecursionLimit = Infinity;
pg = 1 - pe;
alfan = Prepend[ParallelTable[alfa[n, t], {n, 0, N}], 0];
sinalfan1 = Drop[Sin[alfan]^2, 1];
sinalfan2 = Drop[Sin[alfan]^2, -1];
cosalfan = Cos[alfan]^2;
betan = pe*Drop[cosalfan, 1] + (1 - pe)*Drop[cosalfan, -1];
vec[0] = Prepend[ConstantArray[0, N], 1];
Monitor[vec[n_] := vec[n] = betan*vec[n - 1]+
Prepend[Drop[pe*sinalfan1*vec[n - 1], -1], 0] + 
Drop[Append[pg*sinalfan2*vec[n - 1], 0], 1], n];
Return[vec[N]]]
```

Both vettore3 and vettore4 perform in a similar way.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would help a lot I you could describe what the code does. Also, without a few example test cases are necessary to give relevant suggestions.

Comment: I wrould recommend avoiding reshaping arrays and instead of recursion and for loops try using built in vector operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Avoid recursion. It is slow in Mathematica. Better use `Do` or `Fold`.

In particular, it is not meaningful to use the memoization construnction for `vec` in `vettore4`: For computing `vec[n]` you need only to now `vec[n-1]` and afterwards, you can forget entirely about `vec[n-1]` afterwards. So, this memoization may need much more memory than needed to solve the problem; allocation and deallocation of memory -- even if done automatically by Mathematica -- needs is time.

- Avoid `Monitor`. It slows down execution.
- `N` is a built-in symbol. Just don't use it as variable.
- Use packed arrays as much a possible. In particular, make sure that all entries of an array are floating point numbers if in the end the array will contain at least one floating point number.
- Use vectorization of arithmetic operations as much as possible.
- Use operations that change the size of an array (e.g. `Append` and `Drop` etc.) as few as possible.
- Safe a lot of scalar-vector multiplications by precomputing quantities that can be reused (e.g. `pesinalfan` and `pgsinalfan` below).

Here is a version of `vettore3a` that is faster by a factor of 20.

```
vettore3a[t_, pe_, nn_] := 
 Module[{pg, vec0, vec1, alfan, betan, cosalfan, pesinalfan, pgsinalfan},
  pg = 1. - pe;
  alfan = alfa[Range[-1., nn], N[t]];
  cosalfan = Cos[alfan]^2;
  With[{sinalfan = Subtract[1., cosalfan[[2 ;; -2]]]},
   pesinalfan = pe sinalfan;
   pgsinalfan = pg sinalfan;
   ];
  betan = pe Rest[cosalfan] + (1. - pe) Most[cosalfan];
  vec0 = ConstantArray[0., nn + 1];
  vec0[[1]] = 1.;
  Do[
   vec1 = betan vec0;
   vec1[[2 ;;]] += pesinalfan vec0[[;; -2]];
   vec1[[;; -2]] += pgsinalfan vec0[[2 ;;]];
   vec0 = vec1;
   , {nn}];
  vec0
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.